# Maven changing the default permissions without filemode property in mapping

Tags: maven, unix, pom.xml, rpm

In my POM.xml, i haven't mentioned  property in .

In this  section, i am packaging a script to /home/deeraj location.

After i build a RPM & install the RPM, the permissions of /home/deeraj is getting changed to 755. Earlier permission was 700.

Does Maven changes (or) rpm changes the permissions to 755 by default? who does this? And what is the benefit out of it?

Can you please explain?

I have solved it by giving explicitly  to 700 so that i can retain old permissions.

Comment: Can you add the relevant parts of your pom.xml to your question? How do you build your rpm?

Comment: The is usually defined by umask...rpm can change the permissions ? depending what you have defined but as @ChristophBöhme already mentioned without POM is hard to guess..